# make webpack (Nuxt project) choose "module" instead of "main"

Tags: javascript, webpack, nuxt.js, package.json

I have a component library (Vue) that i want to import into my project (Nuxt).

The component library has the following defined in the package.json:

```
{
  "main": "cjs/index.js",
  "module": "index.js",
}
```

Now webpack/nuxt is for some reason choosing "main" which is pointing to the CommonJS build - which is absolutely not working (depending if i extract the CSS in my library i either (`extractCss: true`) get a

> document is not defined

or (`extractCss: false`) a

> The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content"

error.

Everything works fine if i change it to `"main": "index.js"` - however as i understood from various sites this would be bad practice? (e.g. [Blog](https://thedrearlight.com/blog/delivering-js-modules.html):

> main absolutely has to point at a cjs or umd format. Otherwise, we’ll be sort of breaking faith with the wider npm ecosystem.

)

Is there a way i can tell nuxt/webpack to use the "module" path?
Or would it be ok to change the "main" path?

Edit to add versions:
nuxt: 2.13.3
webpack: 4.43.0

Comment: Which version of Nuxt are you using? AFAIK, the package.json for the newer version is straightforward.

Comment: nuxt is up to date... `nuxt@2.13.3`

Comment: @roshnet however maybe i did not express the issue clearly...because the package.json in my nuxt project should indeed be fine...its more the webpack config im wondering about - or however i could change that "main" path is used... (the part about the package.json i posted is the the one from my component library)